# How much Ethereum would we get per year when we go into purely Proof of Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0

Let's say, if a person is holding 32 Ethereum and stake them all, in a year, how many ETH will it become altogether?

Comment: As of 2022-01-05 the APR is 5.1%  https://launchpad.ethereum.org/en/. So you will get 1.632 ETH as rewards after 1 year. You have to aware that the APR is dynamic and it depends on the total staked so it is likely it will decrease over time. If I'm not wrong the minimum is above 4%.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://www.stakingrewards.com/earn/ethereum-2-0/) should answer all your questions on ethereum staking interest.

There is a *reward* calculator, that gives the current APR of 4.65% :

[image]